# Is there an easy way to run bash scripts on R Markdown, using Windows 10?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been learning R Markdown for the past months. It was fairly easy to get Anaconda Python to run within a R Markdown script, but I haven't yet found a way to get to run chunks of bash code within the same document.

Using

````
```{bash}
echo hello world
```
````

I get the error message

/bin/bash: C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0MpNfS\chunk-code-4cbc213a3545.txt: No such file or directory

Might any of you guys know what might be the root of this problem?

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately I don't think knitr knows about WSL yet.

Comment: Actually, it looks like knitr _does_ manage to run bash. The real problem is that the files it's trying to process are in the Windows filesystem, which is not the same as the bash filesystem.

Comment: Oh, alright. Do you have an idea as to how I could make it behave as if it's in a bash filesystem?

It's something the WSL Ubuntu manages to do, for example.

Comment: The host filesystem is in `/mnt`, for example your C: drive is `/mnt/c`, and the file `C:\Users\MyName\foobar` is `/mnt/c/Users/MyName/foobar`. Getting knitr to be aware of this could be interesting.

Comment: I do have WSL installed and it works for me.  Starting R in Windows (not in WSL) and entering `Sys.which("bash")` does locate  bash on my system and then entering this:  `library(rmarkdown); render("testbash.Rmd")` where testbash.Rmd is in the current directory that I started R in and contains the 3 lines shown in the question works for me to produce a testbash.html file with hello world.

Comment: Ha! Very interesting @G.Grothendieck. I did the same thing, and it works for me too. It generates a .html file containing the output. So, my problem would be, that it doesn't work *inline*, meaning, I can't run the chunk of code.

Might there be a workaround for that?

Comment: Are you guys able to reproduce my problem, if instead of knitting the document you just press "run current chunk"? That's what's not working in my case.

Comment: @Michael that implies it's a problem with RStudio, not with knitr or rmarkdown. Try asking on their community forums.

Comment: True. I just added the tag Rstudio to my question.

Comment: @Michael: you can file an issue here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: Done. Anyone is welcome to comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2724

Answer (score 2):

I know maybe is to late but I had the same problem and I find the solution.

First, in Windows 8.1 or if you don´t have the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you can install **Cygwin**: *https://cygwin.com/ > Install Cygwin*

- This is the recommendation pointed out in *R Markdown: The Definitive Guide (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) > 2.7 Other language engines > 2.7.2 Shell scripts*

Second, add Cygwin to the PATH. Usually Cygwin is installed in `C:\cygwin64` and the path to include will be in this case `C:\cygwin64\bin`

Third, check that everything is correct using  `base::Sys.which("bash")` in R

- If everything is correct it will appear something like this `"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"`

Fourth, you can run in a Rmarkdown document, the chunk that you pointed out to double check:

````
```{bash}
echo hello world
```
````