# "Run Current Chunk" not working for bash (on Windows 10)

Tags: bash, rstudio, r-markdown

I created a minimal example:

`{bash}
echo hello world
pwd`

Put this in RMarkdownFile.Rmd, and then knit it. Knitting works!

Now the problem is, that when I want to only run this chunk, using the "Run Current Chunk" option (green triangle), I get the error message

/bin/bash: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW2vc5w\chunk-code-4b187eda7773.txt: No such file or directory

Is this a commonly known error? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: are you running on the windows subsystem for linux?

Comment: No, I'm running the usual Windows 10 RStudio. But if you mean if I'm using the WSL bash inside RStudio, then probably yes. When I type `Sys.which('bash')`, I get  `"C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\bash.exe"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to run bash scripts on R Markdown, using Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117689/is-there-an-easy-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-r-markdown-using-windows-10)